# The magic trick

Tags: logical-deduction, cards, magic

I am here to tell you about two brothers that were doing a magic trick. But not the kind with smoke and mirrors but just a deck of cards and the magic of the human mind. Will you be able to match the bothers wits and figure out whats the trick?

Brother 1 will take a normal, shuffled 52 card deck. He will give it to an audience member to shuffle and pick 5 cards at random. Brother 1 will then pick the 5 cards from the audience member, look at them and pass 4 of them to Brother 2, one by one in exactly the same way.

Brother 2 then takes the 4 cards looks at them and guesses without fail the suit and value of the 5th card left in Brother 1 hand's.

So dear audience member, how do they do the trick?

Hint below:

> Don't look for trickery. It is just logic.